# How to flip iamge in opencv without library functions in python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to flip an image in python but cannot use cv2.flip() as per my design brief. Dose anyone has any ideas to help me? Here is my code so far:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('img/bozu.png')
img = cv2.resize(img, (512, 512))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flip the image like this as well.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('img/bozu.png')
img = cv2.resize(img, (512, 512))

# flip vertically
v_flip = img[::-1]

# flip horizontally
h_flip = img[:, ::-1]

# this is bgr to rgb
bgr2rgb = img[:, :, ::-1]
```

Comment: Wont this be considered as a "library function"? I think the "safest" way will be to implement the manual pixel replacement. Formulas are here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaca7be533e3dac7feb70fc60635adf441

Comment: Your right! Turns out that this was not accepted so I am trying to use the equations. Thanks!